# How can I update 4 columns in 3 different tables in a single SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update 4 columns that have the same names in 3 different tables in mySql. Is there a safe way to do this rather than running 3 different statements?

Is something like `update tablea, tableb, tablec set name='x', preferences = 0 etc where id = 5;` possible.

The tables are different, but the column names are the same.

Comment: Since you want to do this, maybe you should look at your database design.  Storing the same thing in more than one place is a bad idea.

Comment: Why just a single statement? What is the problem with 3 statements? Do you use a non-transactional storage engine?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 tables all with a field called value1, then you can update all 4 tables with a single query. I don't know if it will technically be more efficient but it is possible. Below, I set up the mentioned tables then set multiple different tables' value1's to be equal to 9 if they aren't equal to 9.

Assuming we build this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
  (
    value1 int
  );
CREATE TABLE table2
  (
    value1 int
  );
CREATE TABLE table3
  (
    value1 int
  );
CREATE TABLE table4
  (
    value1 int
  );
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO table2
VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO table3
VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO table4
VALUES(4);
```

You can update multiple tables with the following:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.value1 = 9, table2.value1 = 9
WHERE table1.value1 != 9 OR table2.value1 != 9
```

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3064f/5

Unless you're referring to the execution of SQL via some server-side language:

```
mysqlQuery("SELECT * from table1");
mysqlQuery("SELECT * from table2");
mysqlQuery("SELECT * from table3");
```

Which can just be written as:

```
mysqlQuery("SELECT * from table1; SELECT * from table2; SELECT * from table3");
```

I'm pretty sure. Hope that helps!

Edit: Added SQLfiddle